# How are coordinates defined for row, column, and null spaces of a transformation matrix with arbitrary basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

For a linear transformation $T:R^n \to R^m$ defined by $T(x)=Ax$ where $A$ is some $m \times n$ matrix, to my understanding, if some arbitrary basis is used for both $R^n$ ($\{v_1 ... v_n \}$) and  $R^m$ ($\{u_1 ... u_m \}$), the ith column of $A$ should be the vector $T(v_i) = \begin{bmatrix} c_{1i} \\ c_{2i} \\ \vdots \\ c_{mi}\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{j=1}^mc_{ji}u_j$ where the c's are the coordinates defined in terms of the basis $\{u_1 ... u_m \}$ for $R^m$.

For the subspaces $Col(A), Row(A), Null(A), Null(A^T)$, what basis is used to define the coordinates of the vectors in these spaces? I'm particularly stumped on $Row(A)$ and $Null(A^T)$ since I can't see a relation between it and the domain / range of the transformation for which we defined a basis.

Comment: Some observations, you said that the basis $\{ u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ you took it arbitrary, then the equality
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 c_{1i} \\ c_{2i} \\ \vdots \\ c_{mi}
\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{j=1}^mc_{ji}u_j$$
its false, unless $u_j=e_j$ for all $j$ (where $e_j$ is the vector with a $1$ in the $j$-th entry and $0$ in all others).

Comment: And the truth is that your question does not make much sense, given a $n$-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$ and $\beta=\{ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n \}$ some *arbitrary* basis of it, for every vector $x \in \textsf V$ there exists unique scalars $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ such that
$$x=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jv_j$$
In this case, the coefficients $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are called the *coordinates* of $x$ with respect to $\beta$.

Comment: @Azif00 I got that formula based on this article from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices), where the article defines $f:V \to W$ as the linear map and $f(v_j) = a_{1j}w_1+...+a_{1m}w_m$ where $v_j$ as one basis vector of $V$ and $w_1...w_m$ the basis vectors for $W$. The $a_{1j},...,a_{mj}$ are coordinates of  $f(v_j)$ which go into the $jth$ column of the matrix that describes $f$.